# After Validate (Same page) the value stay on the page

Tags: php

Input(value) stay on the same page when click on "submit"(validation)

http://lab.iamrohit.in/cvalid/   The Code

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="type">
<option value="American">American Express</option>
<option value="Dinners">Diner's Club</option>
<option value="Discover">Discover</option>
<option value="Master">Master Card</option>
<option value="Visa">Visa</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="cNum">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

After click on submit , the input stay on the text box

Comment: you can repopulate it with `<input type="text" name="cNum" value='<?php echo $_POST['cNum']?>'>` it will be empty on first load, so you might want to check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the action in your form that's why the form is by default is submitting to the same page. You can use `autocomplete`.

> Autocomplete allows the browser to predict the value. When a user starts to type in a field, the browser should display options to fill in the field, based on earlier typed values.

```
<input type="text" name="cNum" autocomplete="off">
```

If you want form selected values be as selected after form subimmision, try this

```
$type = '';
$cNum  = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $type = $_POST['type'];
  $cNum = $_POST['cNum'];
 }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
 <select name="type">
    <option value="American" <?php if($type == 'American'):?>selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>American Express</option>
    <option value="Dinners"  <?php if($type == 'Dinners'):?>selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>Diner's Club</option>
    <option value="Discover" <?php if($type == 'Discover'):?>selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>Discover</option>
    <option value="Master"   <?php if($type == 'Master'):?>selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>Master Card</option>
    <option value="Visa"     <?php if($type == 'Visa'):?>selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>Visa</option>
</select>
  <input type="text" name="cNum" value="<?php echo $cNum;?>"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello , thanks for the long explanation,
Okay it works but what if for this code 
 <input type="text" name="cNum" value="<?php echo $cNum;?>"/> 


the original is <input type="text" name="cNum" value="<?php echo $cardpaymentnumber[3];?>"  


There involve of Database , but when i enter new card , it show the new card instead of db value 

$cardpaymentnumber[3] = db value using array

Comment: so that when i did not perform validate in the first place ,it will show db value ,and user able to enter new CC number for validate

Comment: @BlueMoutain please update your question why you are looking for, where you got stuck ?

Comment: @tim There is no syntax error, the code has been Tested before posting here with PHP7 and nginx

Comment: everything is work now , but i will update/post a new thread about the thing i wanted next ( tried it but not working , need help  ) , i will not update the original post , so that when newcomer saw this thread they know what is the thread for . thanks for the help