# PHP validation from newly nput and db value

Tags: php

Last Post: [After Validate (Same page) the value stay on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770478/after-validate-same-page-the-value-stay-on-the-page)

The validate works, but i wanted to improvise it.

Let say when the user clicks on "Submit", the card info will be inserted into the database (on the same page).

I changed the code to this (input):

```
<input type="text" name="cNum" value="<?php echo $cardpaymentnumber[3];?>"
```

`$cardpaymentnumber[3]` is the result of a query.

**Desired result:**

When I go to the page, there will be a credit card number already on the text input (from database).
When I insert new credit card number and validate (submit validation button), the newly inserted data shows in the text field and not the value from the database.

Answer (score 2):

You have to test if the card number field has been submitted :

`$sValue = (isset($_POST['cNum']))?$_POST['cNum']:$cardpaymentnumber[3];
<input type="text" name="cNum" value="<?php echo $sValue;?>" />`